# Woocommerce minimum order for certain product categories and exclude categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have a minimum order amount of 3 products from **Chilled** category.

If there are no **Chilled** category products in the cart and any combination of other product categories (**Bundle**, **Ambient**, **Gifts**) in the cart, the customer should be able to checkout.

If there is less than 3 **Chilled** category products in the cart *but* there is also a **Bundle** category product in the cart, the customer should still be able to checkout.

My `wc_add_notice error` is counting the **Chilled** logic correctly, but it is displaying even when there are no items from the **Chilled** category in the cart.

Please can someone help where I am going wrong?

```
// Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'chilled_set_min_total' );
    function chilled_set_min_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $i=0;
          
            // Set minimum product cart total
            //And initialise product catergory counters
            $minimum_chilled = 3;
            $total_chilled = 0;
            $cat_in_cart = false;
            
            //check if chilled product in cart. If exists add to quantity
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :
                if ( has_term( 'chilled', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) {
                   $total_chilled += $product['quantity'];
                }
                if ( has_term( 'bundles', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
                    $cat_in_cart = true;
                break;
             }
            endforeach;
          //if chilled items is less than minimum display error
            if ($total_chilled < $minimum_chilled) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products are required from The CHILLED category before checking out.</strong>'
                . '<br />Current number of Chilled items in the cart: %s.',
                    $minimum_chilled,
                    $total_chilled ),
                'error' );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this line

> if ($total_chilled < $minimum_chilled) {

if we have no chilled, so $total_chilled dont change and = 0

So we have 0 < 3 and its always = true

To solve this problem you need to add one more check

```
  //Check if there are any products from this category in the cart
  if ($total_chilled > 0) {
  
  //if chilled items is less than minimum display error
    if ($total_chilled < $minimum_chilled) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products are required from The CHILLED category before checking out.</strong>'
        . '<br />Current number of Chilled items in the cart: %s.',
            $minimum_chilled,
            $total_chilled ),
        'error' );
    }
    
    }
```

Update, if you need to disable checkout button add

> remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

```
  //Check if there are any products from this category in the cart
  if ($total_chilled > 0) {
  
  //if chilled items is less than minimum display error
    if ($total_chilled < $minimum_chilled) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products are required from The CHILLED category before checking out.</strong>'
        . '<br />Current number of Chilled items in the cart: %s.',
            $minimum_chilled,
            $total_chilled ),
        'error' );

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

    }
    
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work as it allows the cart to check out if there is less than 3 chilled items.

Comment: Check update, if you need disable checkout button add remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );